# D-Wave systems and IBM Q System One

Tags: experimental-realization, d-wave, ibm-quantum-devices

What is the difference between the D-Wave systems and the newly-born IBM Q System One?

Comment: Hi, Xiaohua. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! Please note that you should not ask two separate (non-overlapping/unrelated) questions in the same thread. I've [edit]ed to remove your second question i.e. "Are the D-wave systems intended for applications to artificial intelligence?". I hope you don't mind. If you really intend to ask that question, please ask it in a new thread (also review [ask]).

Answer (score 5):

When referring to the commercial quantum computers of both parties, it is that both are based on a different quantum principles.

The D-Wave machine works via quantum annealing and is suited for optimization problems. The machine by IBM is a gate-based quantum computer, similar to how digital computers work at the elementary level.

As the two quantum paradigms differ, it is also hard to compare them based on for instance the number of qubits (~2,000 vs. 20). The details of both machines can easily be found online.

Comment: Thanks nippon for your answer. I also find another interesting answer. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/how-to-explain-in-layman-s-terms-the-significance-of-the-difference-of-qubits-of?rq=1.